# Как получить содержание колонок в Excel файле через Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, обработка-данных

Работаю с таблицей структуры1:

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py93V.png]

Нужно получить содержание определённых колонок, для этого использую конструкцию `df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename)[['1', '2', '21']]`, но программа закрывается с ошибкой.

Если данную конструкцию применить на таблице структуры2:

[image: структура2]

то всё проходит без ошибок.

Мой код:

```
import time
import pandas as pd

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog



class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(775, 374)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 50, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 240, 121, 21))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 191, 20))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 120, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 190, 91, 23))
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 80, 191, 20))
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 150, 191, 20))
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 40, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.textEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 110, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit_2.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit_2.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit_2.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit_2.setObjectName("textEdit_2")
        self.textEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QPlainTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit_3.setEnabled(True)
        self.textEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(190, 180, 341, 41))
        self.textEdit_3.setAcceptDrops(True)
        self.textEdit_3.setInputMethodHints(QtCore.Qt.ImhMultiLine)
        self.textEdit_3.setTextInteractionFlags(QtCore.Qt.TextEditorInteraction)
        self.textEdit_3.setObjectName("textEdit_3")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 775, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Сравнить"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Добавить"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Загрузите файл"))


        class ShowPath(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):


        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)
            self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.getFileName1)
            self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.getFileName2)
            self.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(self.comparison)

            self.filename = None
            self.filename1 = None
            self.filename2 = None

        def getFileName(self):
            self.filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
            self.textEdit.clear()
            self.textEdit.appendHtml(f"<b>{self.filename}</b>")

        def getFileName1(self):
            self.filename1, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,"Выбрать файл",".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
            self.textEdit_2.clear()
            self.textEdit_2.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(self.filename1))

        def getFileName2(self):
            self.filename2, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выбрать файл", ".","Excel 2007(*.xlsx);;Excel 97-2003(*.xls)")
            self.textEdit_3.clear()
            self.textEdit_3.appendHtml("<br><b>{}</b> <br> <b></b>""".format(self.filename2))

        def comparison(self):

            df1 = pd.read_excel(self.filename)[['1', '2', '21']]
            #df2 = pd.read_excel(self.filename1) [[]]
            #difference = df1[df1 != df2]
            print(df1)
            #print(df2)
            #print(df1 != df2)

            #print(difference)
            timestr = time.strftime("%d%m%Y_%H%M%S")

            df1.to_excel(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Результат.xlsx")

            print(timestr)
            print("Работатет!!!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ShowPath()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Очевидно, что в первом случае у вас мультииндекс. укажите при открытии файла явным образом строку с наименованием колонок. И потом, не стоит приводить 500 страниц кода, нерелевантного вопросу - пропадает всякое желание такой вопрос читать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в многоуровневом наименовании столбцов. Поэтому в данном случае можно пропустить строки с наименованиями столбцов и обращаться к столбцам по их порядковому номеру:

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename, skiprows=2, header=None, usecols=[0,1,19])
```